# Set session expiry time

Tags: php, session

How can I set the session expiry time to 10 minutes for the whole of my site?
I cannot use the `php.ini` as its on shared hosting.

Is there a global method I could use?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - make session expire after X minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770150/php-make-session-expire-after-x-minutes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think so.

You can save the timestamp of the last refresh of your website into a session and compare it with the current time on the next reload.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['expiretime'])) {
    if($_SESSION['expiretime'] < time()) {
        //logged out
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['expiretime'] = time() + 600;
    }
}
//maybe add some login procedures and than execute the following line
$_SESSION['expiretime'] = time() + 600;
```

Answer (score 2):

Realy tricky subject , you can use the following :

```
session_set_cookie_params(600);
```

Witch actualy sets the cookie params , so the cookie expires after 10 min , when the user makes a request the browser whont send the phpsessid cookie so php will issue a new session . The problem is that it whont unset the previous session so the previous session will still be valid .

[session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Comment: session_set_cookie_params() expires all the available sessions after given time. but no one wants to destroy all the sessions. what if ppl wnt to expire specific session but not all??