# Automatic Log-off

Tags: php, session, timeout, logout

How do i create a script that will log out the user after 10 minutes of inactivity.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - make session expire after X minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770150/php-make-session-expire-after-x-minutes)

Comment: the difference is the inactivity part I guess?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time the user does something, update a timestamp in a table somewhere for that user. Have a cron job on the server that looks in that table, and logs out anyone that is logged in but haven't had his timestamp updated in ten minutes.

Comment: OK.  I get the idea of how to do it.  But how can i integrate it into my code:  Here it is:                if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/log.php')
{
    header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]");
}

Comment: Hm, totally depends on exactly what you want to do. I meant that you could store it in a database table. But you should be able to do something like if(isset($_SESSION['lastActivityTimestamp'] && $_SESSION['lastActivityTimestamp'] < ten minutes ago) logout();

Comment: OK.  I am going to be trying it soon.  I will get back to you if i have any problems.  thanks Stefan.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP, include this code in commonfile

```
if(isset($_SESSION['last_activetime'])){    
   if(time() - $_SESSION['last_activetime'] > 600) { 
        header("location:logout.php");
        exit;
   }    
}
$_SESSION['last_activetime'] = time(); // when user open page time store in session
```

Answer (score 1):

[PHP - make session expire after X minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770150/php-make-session-expire-after-x-minutes)
 :)